# How to implement Continue Reading feature?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I want to implement Continue Reading in my app.

1. How do I find all the device connected to the computer or the phone?
2. How do I open the app from the other device?

**For Reference**

I like the way [MSPoweruser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/mspoweruser/9nblggh3lhg8) app has implemented this feature. In that app If we click Continue Reading button, it will show all the devices connected to this device. So if I click on a device it will open the app on that device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an SDK for that in UWP - [Project Rome](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/connected-apps-and-devices).

Comment: I completely forget about Project Rome even after watching BUILD 2017. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In many ways.

For example:

Your server where to register the user's avaliable devices. If user push "Continue" button device get all avaliable devices and show list. After user choice, device send state to new device.

Or

You send state to server after push button and new device get state from server.

Comment: Can you provide sample code for opening app remotely?

Comment: @VijayNirmal This is system dependent. But bacically your app or your app runner must run on device and wait to start signal if you want automatic "run".

Comment: Then I should create a background Task that checks Continuously for the signal. Am I right?

Comment: @VijayNirmal You can use SignalR lib which can hanldle this. But this depends on architecture which you chose. Mayby manual app start and get data from server will be better aproach. This is too broad for StackOverflow

Comment: This would work, but in UWP there is already an SDK for this - Project Rome SDK so I'd rather use that. MSPoweruser uses it too.